# Node: AWS S3 sdk sync from different accounts

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Hello I am having an issue with S3 buckets.

I have different environments dev, qa, staging and production, each s3 bucket have a specific IAM role per environment, so it won't be possible to share the same AWS Api keys.

What I need is the possibility to sync content from `{ENV_1}_S3_Bucket to {ENV_2}_S3_Bucket` using the nodejs aws sdk.

Is there anything that can help ? I wouldn't like to mess a lot with the IAM roles.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Answer (score 1):

The role you want to access the bucket with must be explicit listed in the S3 Bucket Policy:

(S3 web console -> the bucket -> tab Permissions -> button Bucket Policy)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/your-bucket-role-1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/your-bucket-role-1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```